# Is MOCK_METHOD* not enough?

Tags: googletest, googlemock

Inspired by that Google doc "ForDummies" :), I am trying a simple Google Mock with Google Test example as follows:

```
    #include <gtest/gtest.h>
    #include <gmock/gmock.h>

    using ::testing::_;

    class A
    {
    public:
        A()
        {
            std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
        }
        virtual ~A()
        {
            std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;
        }
        virtual int incVirtual(int i)
        {
            return i + 1;
        }
    };
    class MockA: public A
    {
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD1(incVirtual, int(int));
    };


    TEST(Test, IncTest) {
        MockA a;
        EXPECT_CALL(a, incVirtual(_));
        printf("n == %d\n", a.incVirtual(0));
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
        return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    }
```

When I run it, I get `n == 0`:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from Test
[ RUN      ] Test.IncTest
A()
n == 0
~A()
```

whereas I expect it to be `n == 1`. So I wonder if just defining MOCK_METHODx in the mock class is not enough for mocking the base class method and something additional needs to be done to make `MockA::incVirtual` call `A::incVirtual`?

Answer (score 0):

This is behaving the way it should. By mocking your function, the `MockA` class has essentially overridden the `A` class implementation with a "do nothing" implementation.

If you want to call `A::incVirtual()` when calling `MockA::incVirtual()`, try the following

```
EXPECT_CALL(a, incVirtual(_)).WillOnce(Invoke(&a, &A::incVirtual));
```

Comment: might not work. Calling via member function pointer is dynamic (virtual call) - so infinite recursion might happen. Your should try to run `Invoke([&a](int b) { return a.A::incVirtual(b); })` or add some `int baseIncVirtual(int a) { return A::invokeVirtual(a); }` to `MockA` - and use in in `Invoke`...